# Can I change my nickname in ZombsRoyale mobile?

Tags: mobile, zombsroyale.io

On mobile when you create a new account it asks you to choose a nickname, for example I chose **Player**, it shows up as **Player #6677** (because there are many people who also have that name.)

I want to change my name but I can't see an option to do so. Can I even change my name in ZombsRoyale mobile? I don't want to make another account.

*I'm using android*

Answer (score 2):

You tap the setting gear on mobile and it's in settings.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been wanting to do this as well for a long time, and I’ve finally found an option to do so. I don’t blame you for not seeing it, as it’s really out of the way and tiny.

Click on the friends tab, then click the small “Change Zombs ID” button. It is in the wider of the two boxes, next to the “Your Zombs ID: ” You’ll be able to do this once for free, but after the first time it will start costing Gems.

EDIT: Better description:
The “Change Zombs ID” button can be found in the friends tab, below the purple invite button.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, you can't change your name in zombsroyale.io mobile. People are getting it wrong, they say you can change your username (Player#1234) but you can't change your NICKNAME on mobile. On pc you can change it anytime for free but mobile doesn't have that feature available.

Answer (score -1):

OK before you go into game it says nickname at the top you can change it there or go to friends it will say change id name change that.